# Checkbox with custom image CSS code not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a custom image to a checkbox and I'm using this code:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }

input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
       background-image: url("../images/checkbox-bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;
       height: 16px;
       width: 16px;
       display:inline-block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   }
```

The path is right but the image is not even showing.

I need the image to appear to the left of the label.

Can anyone see a problem on the code above please?

Thanks

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /><label>The Label</label>
```

Comment: write your HTML code also..where u want image? **in place of** checkbox or **in front of** checkbox?

Comment: The label is still a problem as it's under the image and not on the right of it.

Comment: is there label anywhere else on html or only with the checkbox

Comment: updated question with html code.

Comment: How big is the image `../images/checkbox-bg.png`? What are its dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you want to set position and repeat option for background, you should use `background` instead of `background-image`. 
also as I know the background position should appear before repeat option. but I am not sure. try it.

```
background: url("../images/checkbox-bg.png") top left no-repeat;
```

and do not forget, if your css selector is in a seperate stylesheet file, image path should be relative to address of your .css file! if you placed your css selector in you html page, image path should be relative to your html file!

Comment: I added your Answer and also :   width:220px;  ... and although it's better, the label still starts under the checkbox image.

Comment: why you do not change display:inline-block; to display:inline? or can you upload an image from ?

Answer (score 7):

Try using instead of background-image.

```
background: url("") no-repeat 0 0;
```

If that fails add also;

```
display: block;
```

and position it absolutely or float it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign the `background` shorthand format to the `background-image` property.

The following...

```
background-image: url("../images/checkbox-bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

... should instead be:

```
background: url("../images/checkbox-bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;
```

You can also try validating the CSS to see what I mean: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

You can read more about the [background shorthand property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background) and the [background-image property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-image) on the w3C: