# Icheck style is not applied in ajax databind in datatable

Tags: c#, css, ajax, datatables, icheck

I am using `iCheck` plug-in with `datatable.js` in my web application.

I use a ajax request to databind this table.

[image]

Please see my code below.

**Html**

```
<table id="tblCountry" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-highlight table-checkable"
                        data-display-rows="10"
                        data-info="true"
                        data-search="true"
                        data-paginate="true"                            >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="checkbox-column" style="min-width: 50px;">
                                    <input id="thCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="icheck-input" />
                                </th>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th style="min-width: 100px;">Country</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

**Script**

```
    ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("GetTestCountryList", "Invoice")';

    dtTable = $("#tblCountry").dataTable({
        sAjaxSource: ajaxUrl,
        aoColumns: [
            {
                "sClass": "checkbox-column",
                bSortable: false,
                "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this)" class="icheck-input">';
                }
            },
            { sTitle: "Id", bSortable: false, bVisible: false, },
            { sTitle: "Name", bSortable: true, },
        ],
    });
```

**Source**

```
    public ActionResult GetTestCountryList()
    {

        List<Country> lstCountry = new List<Country>();

        lstCountry.Add(new Country { Id = 1, Name = "India" });
        lstCountry.Add(new Country { Id = 2, Name = "USA" });
        lstCountry.Add(new Country { Id = 3, Name = "France" });
        lstCountry.Add(new Country { Id = 4, Name = "Germiny" });
        lstCountry.Add(new Country { Id = 5, Name = "Britan" });

        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = lstCountry.Select(e => new string[]
            {
                "",
                e.Id.ToString(),
                e.Name
            }).ToArray()
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My problem is the check box style is only applied in the header not applied in the rows. Is there any fault in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call icheck from the datatables DrawCallBack - I had the same issue...

```
$('.ajax-datatable').dataTable({
    responsive: false,
    order: [],
    sPaginationType: "simple_numbers",
    bJQueryUI: true,
    bProcessing: false,
    bServerSide: true,
    bStateSave: true,
    sAjaxSource: $('.ajax-datatable').data('source'),
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets":[$('.ajax-datatable').data('targets')]}
    ],

    "fnPreDrawCallback": function() {
        $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="<%= asset_path 'ajax-loader.gif'%>" />',css: { backgroundColor: 'none', border: '0px'} });
        return true;
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        $.unblockUI();
        icheck();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It helped me out wonderfully well.Any way I am curious to know about `$.unblockUI();`

Answer (score 1):

add a checked attribute like this

```
  return '<input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this)" class="icheck-input" checked>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I change my script mrender to 
"mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this)" class="icheck-input" checked>';
                        //icheckbox_minimal-blue icheck-input checked
                    }
 But it's not make any changes in the style.There is no changes in the checkbox style.

Comment: Since it's a javascript file you need to refresh  the page. I think

Comment: Sure. I refresh my page the only changes happens in the check box checked state. But the check box does not appear in the iCheck Box style

Comment: Ok since the checkbox state is happening maybe your problem now is the css or the check image itself. That what you need to check why it is not showing. but your code is ok now.

Comment: Take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702075/checkbox-with-custom-image-css-code-not-working since you are using iCheck library try checking if the path of checkmark image is correct.