# Style radiobutton without using JS or CSS3 or HTML5

Tags: css

I was tasked to create following radiobutton without using JS or CSS3 or HTML5. Is it possible somehow?

[image]

Comment: Please check this website (You need CSS at least) - http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: I've already checked it and all those methods use CSS3. I'm limited to CSS2.1.

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702075/checkbox-with-custom-image-css-code-not-working

Comment: Please move an image into the question instead of relying on the link.

Comment: This was hilariously hard to do.  Probably impossible without Javascript being used in place of CSS3.  Anyway, see if this works for you: http://codepen.io/JaxoDI/pen/VYVbOB

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot post images here, since I have not enough posts.

Comment: @LuisP.A. CSS attribute background-position is also CSS3, so I cannot use it.

Comment: @ScottKaye You solution also uses CSS attribute background-position which is CSS3 and I cannot use it.

Comment: Background-position is CSS2 - http://www.devguru.com/technologies/CSS2/8049 or http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-position

Comment: Ok, split the image into two parts, one active, one inactive, and change the background-image in the Javascript instead of the background-position.

Comment: @LuisP.A. ah I see it is CSS2, but still IE8 and old mobile browsers does not support it.

Comment: @ScottKaye unfortunately, I cannot use JS.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... try this:

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    opacity:0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
       background: url("http://www.csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_796472012f96c8785e1ab96779a4ee3c.png") no-repeat 0 0px;
       height: 40px;
       width: 40px;
       display:block;
       padding: 0px;
   }

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
   {
       background: url("http://www.csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_796472012f96c8785e1ab96779a4ee3c.png") no-repeat 0 -40px;

   }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /><label></label>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/u97d9vn0/)**

Comment: `:checked` was introduced by [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#selector-checked) and [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked).